# How to get file.creationtime attribute in nifi groovy script

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I need to get file creation time which needs to be stored in a database. I am using executescript processor. `flowFile.getAttribute('file.creationTime')` returns null. Any idea how to get the `file.creationTime` attribute value of the flowfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ExecuteScript` processor is used to run arbitrary scripts that can't be done with Apache NiFi's *native* processors. The `ListFile` processor will retrieve information about a file, and if the `Include File Attributes` processor property is set to `true`, it will include metadata including the file creation time in the attribute `file.creationTime`.

If this attribute is null, there are a few possible reasons and ways to investigate:

1. Stop the processor that follows `ListFile` and right click on the connection to reveal a context menu with the option *List Queue*. This will let you examine the flowfiles in the queue. You can inspect them for this attribute (among others) to see if it is populated. You can also use a `LogAttribute` processor to print the flowfile attributes to your `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` file.

   - If it is not, your `ListFile` processor might have that processor property set to `false`, or the file system might not support that metadata.
   - If it is, check that the Groovy reference you are acting on is correct and points to a flowfile that has that attribute.